# How to count only visible cells in a custom function (count cells based on cell colour)

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a custom function that I found on the net. It does what I need it to do - counts cells of specific colour in a range of cells.

How do I edit it to only count visible cells? 
I have tried to use this, but it doesn't doo anything.

```
For Each rCell In CountRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Complete function is this:

```
    Function GetColorCount(CountRange As Range, CountColor As Range, Optional VolatileParameter As Variant)
Dim CountColorValue As Integer
Dim TotalCount As Integer
CountColorValue = CountColor.Interior.ColorIndex
Set rCell = CountRange
For Each rCell In CountRange
  If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = CountColorValue Then
    TotalCount = TotalCount + 1
  End If
Next rCell
GetColorCount = TotalCount
End Function
```

To use it in the worksheet I then type:

```
=GetColorCount(A1:G20,H1, NOW())
```

Where:

- A1:G20 is the range I want to count all yellow cells
- H1 is cell where count is displayed and is coloured in yellow
- NOW() makes it run everytime a change is made in the range (??)

Any tips?

Comment: I believe `SpecialCells` won't work within a `UDF`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Function GetColorCount(CountRange As Range, CountColor As Range, Optional VolatileParameter As Variant)
 Dim ColVal As Long, rCell As Range
 Dim TotalCount As Long
 ColVal = CountColor.Interior.ColorIndex
    For Each rCell In CountRange.Cells
      If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = ColVal Then
          If rCell.EntireRow.Hidden = False And _
              rCell.EntireColumn.Hidden = False Then
              TotalCount = TotalCount + 1
          End If
      End If
    Next rCell
 GetColorCount = TotalCount
End Function
```

`SpecialCells` cannot be used in UDF, but checking of each cell in the range visibility is possible...

Comment: Great solution FaneDuru! Works a treat! Thx for taking time to answer

Comment: Welcome! But Solutions posted by @CLR should also work. And it is an interesting workaround... Ups. Only now I could see that you confirmed that (in a way) :)

Comment: This is basically identical to my earlier answer.. but I'm just wondering why you switch OPs CountColorValue (your ColVal) to a Long? Being a `.Colorindex` it only requires an Integer as it's 0 to 56.

Comment: @CLR - but [there's no benefit to using Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long).

Comment: No benefit to keeping it Integer, no, but possible confusion to the OP in changing it? When we're lucky enough to actually get an OPs existing code, I try to only change those parts that need it.

Comment: @CLR: Just a matter of habit. No any benefit of using Integer, but it may be problematic if you use it instead of Long, in some cases. And yes, I was working to  my answer (in  my way) and you wore the first posting it... They are similar enough. It is a normal way of solving such a challenge, I think.

Comment: @FaneDuru: no worries.

Comment: @CLR: I want no worried... English is not my best point and maybe it is good to say that when I said something about "the normal way" I wanted to say that such a problem could have only similar ways/code of solving it.

Answer (score 1):

`SpecialCells` is indeed flaky when wrapped in a UDF like this.

Here is a solution/workaround by checking the row height and column width for zero. I'm sure others exist but this is one way of achieving your goal.

```
Function GetColorCount(CountRange As Range, CountColor As Range, Optional VolatileParameter As Variant)
    Dim CountColorValue As Integer
    Dim TotalCount As Integer
    CountColorValue = CountColor.Interior.ColorIndex
    For Each rcell In CountRange.Cells
        If rcell.Interior.ColorIndex = CountColorValue Then
            If (rcell.EntireRow.Height * rcell.EntireColumn.Width) <> 0 Then
                TotalCount = TotalCount + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next rcell
    GetColorCount = TotalCount
End Function
```

Comment: Thx CRL. This works as well as the other answer I received. Hope this will be useful for other members of this group :)